# If there any possible ways to put Asynctask on handling Intent data. I want parse some JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, android-asynctask

There is my problem to solve, if possible to put asynctask inside handleIntent? How?

```
/**
 * Handling intent data
 */
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        txtQuery.setText("Search Query: " + query);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course this is possible. How have you tried to do it? What errors did you get?

Comment: honestly, i havent tried to put asynctask yet, i confused how. I'am new for android programming. Can you give me how do i implement the asyntask inside code above. pliss

Comment: There is nothing special in your code. Take any asynctask example and go ahead.

Comment: yes i did, but how i put the asynctask inside the handleIntent? or inside code above i just call for execute asynctask?